# Javascript onmousemove and onclick

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to change  background color when mouse is clicked and over the element with possibility to move it so that you don't have to click on every element but insted be able to 'draw' with mouse. But I don't know how.
My code for now goes like

```js
function change_color(x, y) {
  console.log(x, y);
  var elem = document.getElementById(x.toString() + "-" + y.toString());
  if (elem.style.backgroundColor == 'white')
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  else
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```css
#board td {
  /*border: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);*/
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
  <tr>
    <td id='0-0' onmousedown="change_color(0,0);"></td>
    <td id='0-1' onmousedown="change_color(0,1);"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='1-0' onmousedown="change_color(1,0);"></td>
    <td id='1-1' onmousedown="change_color(1,1);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a few changes.

1. Try using classes instead of inline styles. This allows you to toggle the class using a simple `classList.toggle()`.
2. I'd attach the events using `addEventListener` instead of inline on the elements themselves, both for cleanliness and reducing duplicate code.
3. You can use `e.which` to determine if the mouse is down when hovering over an element. If `e.which === 1`, the primary mouse button is down.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#board td").forEach((e) => { //for each board td
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", change_color);        //change color on hover
  e.addEventListener("mousedown", change_color);        //change color on click
});

function change_color(e) {
  if (e.which !== 1) return;             //exit if mouse isn't down
  e.target.classList.toggle('black');    //toggle black background
}
```

```css
#board td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#board td.black { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<table id="board">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of variable to know if the mouse is down and use a mousemove event.

```js
let isDown = false
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  isDown = true
});

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  isDown = false
});

document.getElementById("grid").addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {
  if (isDown) evt.target.classList.add("active")
})
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}

td{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px dotted #eee;
}

td.active {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<table id="grid">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `onmousemove` to call a function. Each time that function is called (i.e. each time the mouse moves) you can check if the mouse button is down and then change the colour of the pixel.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousemove